# Conditions for $f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ to be $C^p$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^p$ function. I'm looking for a necessary and sufficient condition for the function $$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$$ to be $C^p$ as well. Now, obviously, it is $C^p$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ so the unique problem is at $(0,0)$.

I have used some brute force and compute partial derivatives up to order 3. It seems that a sufficient condition is the cancelation of all the derivatives of $f$ at $0$. However it is just a conjecture and, moreover, it would only be a sufficient condition not a necessary one.

Any help or thought on this subject will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would then suggest you computing the derivatives by definition at $(0,0)$ and find out that a necessary condition is $f'(0) = 0$. Then it seems like a good idea to check whether it will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $f(0)=0$, if needed by replacing $f$ by $f-f(0)$.

If $f^\prime(0)=0$, it exists $\epsilon : \mathbb  R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lim\limits_{r \to 0} \epsilon(r)= 0$ and

$$f(r) = r \epsilon(r).$$ Therefore

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f\left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$ proving that $g(x,y) = f\left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and that its derivative  there is the always vanishing map.

Conversely, it is easy to prove that if $f^\prime(0) = a \neq 0$ then $g$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ as for $\lambda \gt 0$ we have

$$g(\lambda,0) = a \vert \lambda \vert + \vert \lambda \vert \epsilon(\vert \lambda \vert ).$$

**We would need to conclude to study the continuity of $g^\prime$ at $(0,0)$.**